# Execute Testng tests in parallel with Data Provider

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

I am trying to execute testng tests in parallel with Data Provider. Each input of Data Provider will be a new test.
For parallel execution, i have added attribute parallel to data provider & threadPoolSize to Test.
I am passing command line arguments in eclipse Run Configuration -parallel methods -dataproviderthreadcount 2
Below is code snippet tried so far

```
  public class DemoTest { 

  @Test(dataProvider = "dp",invocationCount=1,threadPoolSize=2)
  public void f(Integer n, String s) {
  System.out.println("id:"+Thread.currentThread().getId()+" n:"+n+" s:"+s);
  }

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod() {
 }

 @AfterMethod
 public void afterMethod() {
 }


 @DataProvider(parallel=true)
 public Object[][] dp() {
return new Object[][] {
  new Object[] { 1, "a" },
  new Object[] { 2, "b" },
  new Object[] { 3, "c" },
  new Object[] { 4, "d" },
  new Object[] { 5, "e" },
  new Object[] { 6, "f" },
  new Object[] { 7, "g" },
  new Object[] { 8, "h" },
  new Object[] { 9, "i" },
  new Object[] { 10,"j" }
  };
 }
}
```

Output:
id:10 n:1 s:a
id:14 n:5 s:e
id:17 n:8 s:h
id:13 n:4 s:d
id:11 n:2 s:b
id:15 n:6 s:f
id:12 n:3 s:c
id:19 n:10 s:j
id:18 n:9 s:i
id:16 n:7 s:g

A new thread is created for each input, but I want only 2 threads to be created.

Comment: Please refer to [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Comment: What is you testng version? Could you try with a `testng.xml` instead of params?

Comment: testng version 6.9.6 @juherr.

Comment: I have to try without using a testng.xml file. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't know if command line in the Eclipse plugin is working. That's why you should try with TestNG.xml first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestNG parallel Execution with DataProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521466/testng-parallel-execution-with-dataprovider)